# Override dialog method from mother class

Tags: class, dialog, overriding, super

:

I have a super class and a child class.
The super class have a dialog method.
When I run superclass it runs well showing his dialog method
Depending on combobox opion, I call construct methods
for the new instancs of child classes.
The super class call the child class (it is ok)
but the child class have a dialog method also.
How I can override dialog from superclass
and show the dialog of current child class?.

Regards

that child class see his dialg method not super class dialog method